# Rails 3 show/hide div on edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have the following in my view...

```
 <fieldset class="learner-registration">
   <p>
    <%= event_form.check_box :requires_registration %>
    <%= event_form.label :requires_registration, 'Require participants to register (optional)' %>
    <%= event_form.text_field :evaluator_id, :class => "form-control" %>
    <span class="help-block">Particpants cannot view Event Location until they enter email and name</span>
   </p>
 </fieldset>
```

...and the following coffeescript...

```
jQuery ->
    $("#event_evaluator_id").hide()
    $('#event_requires_registration').change ->
        $('#event_evaluator_id').toggle @checked
        return
```

This works great, and toggles the event_evaluator_id field like I want, in addtion to hiding it that field on initial page load. The issue I am having is when editing the page, the check/unchecked property is not persisting. So with the code above if I have a checked checkbox, the event_evaluator_id field is hidden when I edit the page.

I tried something like...

```
jQuery ->
    if $("#event_requires_registration").val() = null
        $("#event_evaluator_id").hide()
    else
        $("#event_evaluator_id").show()
    $('#event_requires_registration').change ->
        $('#event_evaluator_id').toggle @checked
        return
```

...but the event_evaluator_id field ends up visible all the time (checked or unchecked). Any help appreciated.

## EDIT

Also here is the html on the checkbox:

```
<input checked="checked" id="event_requires_registration" name="event[requires_registration]" type="checkbox" value="1">
```

What I am seeing is the value of 'value' is 1 whether is is checked or unchecked.

Comment: try this `if $("#event_requires_registration").val().length > 0`...

Comment: @PardeepDhingra See my edit above.  The value of 'value' is 1 whether is is checked or unchecked.

Comment: $('#event_requires_registration').is ':checked'

Comment: @PardeepDhingra that works dude. If you want to add an answer I'll upvote and accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#event_requires_registration').is ':checked'
```

Here is the whole thing for context sake:

```
jQuery ->
    if $("#event_requires_registration").is ':checked'
        $("#event_evaluator_id").show()
    else
        $("#event_evaluator_id").hide()
    $('#event_requires_registration').change ->
        $('#event_evaluator_id').toggle @checked
        return
```